# Hide Dialog from inside in LWUIT

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-dialog

I have created a `Dialog` with two buttons Yes, No, and then I have add action listener to them, my problem is that I want no button to hide the `Dialog` that I have created

the code is looks like:

```
dialog = new Dialog(title);
        dialog.setDialogType(Dialog.TYPE_CONFIRMATION);

        ta = new TextArea(text);
        ta.getStyle().setBorder(Border.createEmpty());
        ta.setEditable(false);
        yesCommand = new Button("YES");
        noCommand = new Button("NO");

        yesCommand.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                LGBMainMidlet.getLGBMidlet().notifyDestroyed();
            }
        });

        noCommand.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                Logger.Log("Bye Bye");
                dialog = null;
                System.gc();
            }
        });

        dialog.addComponent(ta);
        dialog.addComponent(yesCommand);
        dialog.addComponent(noCommand);
        dialog.show();
```

the code is not working for me, can anyone told me what is the problem?

B.N. I have used `dialog.dispose()`, but it exit the whole application

Comment: But, what you want is to hide the Dialog when you press a command or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dialog.dispose()` does not exit the whole application, it just closes the dialog.
If you have nothing in your application you might see nothing if you dispose the dialog.

Comment: It works, I was have problem and when I solve it the dispose method works

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use 
dialog.setTimeout(1000); the number show the time limit the dialog box wait in milliseconds. So by doing this you can exit the dialog form automatically.